# How does an assembler place a constant in a file as data, and how is it executed that way?

Tags: assembly

For example, in Assembly x86 we can use the .data entry section and statically define a data byte like this:

```
MSG db 'CAGA', AAFF
```

My question concerns how or what the Assembler does to achieve that data being inserted on the binary file, assuming we are assembling to a flat binary (bin) file.

I want to know because I am attempting to decompile, and get a better understanding of how to work with machine code programming as well.

See, I want to code system software in machine code, but the Assembler abstracts away some machine code concepts (like static data declarations, alignment, instruction width, structuring of statements, operands, or code in general) and I am at a standstill.

I am simply asking how, in regards to machine code, is it laid out within these fundamentals:

How is the .data portion of the program statically added to the file, and how does it then get used in run-time/processing time when the CPU fetches the instruction? For example, in this program below, which is an x86 bootloader in Intel syntax Assembly code on FASM,

```
    [BITS 16]   ;Tells the assembler that its a 16 bit code
[ORG 0x7C00]    ;Origin, tell the assembler that where the code will
                ;be in memory after it is been loaded

MOV SI, HelloString ;Store string pointer to SI
CALL PrintString    ;Call print string procedure
JMP $       ;Infinite loop, hang it here.


PrintCharacter: ;Procedure to print character on screen
    ;Assume that ASCII value is in register AL
MOV AH, 0x0E    ;Tell BIOS that we need to print one charater on screen.
MOV BH, 0x00    ;Page no.
MOV BL, 0x07    ;Text attribute 0x07 is lightgrey font on black background

INT 0x10    ;Call video interrupt
RET     ;Return to calling procedure



PrintString:    ;Procedure to print string on screen
    ;Assume that string starting pointer is in register SI

next_character: ;Lable to fetch next character from string
MOV AL, [SI]    ;Get a byte from string and store in AL register
INC SI      ;Increment SI pointer
OR AL, AL   ;Check if value in AL is zero (end of string)
JZ exit_function ;If end then return
CALL PrintCharacter ;Else print the character which is in AL register
JMP next_character  ;Fetch next character from string
exit_function:  ;End label
RET     ;Return from procedure


;Data
HelloString db 'Hello World', 0 ;HelloWorld string ending with 0

TIMES 510 - ($ - $$) db 0   ;Fill the rest of sector with 0
DW 0xAA55           ;Add boot signature at the end of bootloader
```

"**HelloString db 'Hello World', 0**" is statically inserted in to the bin file as 0s and 1s, but how, in machine code, does the static binary data get added as an operand to the MOV SI instruction by storing a string pointer address to the register?

Basically, how is the static binary data byte in the file executed as a code operand to be moved in to the Source Index register?

Answer (score 0):

`MOV SI, HelloString`

is really shorthand for

`MOV SI, OFFSET HelloString`

The actual string HelloString is placed in the binary stream just like code would as a sequence of bytes. For segmented code it's often in a separate data segment that can varying names depending on the platform. For things like COM files the data typically just follows the code area, typically starting on a suitably aligned address.

UPDATE:

I don't have access to a 16-bit system right now, but here's what something similar literally looks like in 32 bit x86 code:

```
Binary code    Instruction
BEA43F4600     mov esi, offset @HelloString  
E8F2FFFFFF     call PrintString
EBFE           @1: jmp @1
48656C6C6F     @HelloString: "Hello"
```

Of course the actual offset of @HelloString and the actual address of PrintString depends on the context.

Comment: I don't quite get it - could you define in pics or maybe more in depth?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question depends a litlle bit on how your binary file is executed.

Assuming for the moment an operating system is used like Linux or MS-windows,
a binary file is complicated, with header information and such. Let's ignore that and 
concentrate how it looks once the program is in memory.

It is slightly simpler.

**code area**

**code prelude**

`MOV AL,BL` 
  ...

**code postlude**

**data area**

MYDATA:
   data "caga",0AH

The area's are traditionally called segments. Now that name is hijacked by Intel and they are called sections, by Microsoft as well as linux (ELF). There is a strong relation though.
The MOV is where your program starts,  but there is a need for a setup prelude
 and for a postlude (or you would never get back to Linux again).
In a typical Linux/Windows situation on a Pentium, you'll see that the sections are supported by the Intel segment hardware. The bottom line is, you will not be able to jump to MYDATA, i.e. set the program counter to contain MYDATA. Instead the hardware will treat you to a "segmentation fault" on linux, and maybe a blue screen on Windows.

To be sure, you can execute "data", because in fact code is just data that is at the right place and time to be executed. E.g. you can force what follows to be executable by putting in a line like
`SECTION .text`

(Silly, I know. I.m not making this up.)

In an assembler program code section you can say
`MOV AL,BL` 
and it will put 0x88 and 0xD8 in the code segment in two successive bytes.
The same effect can be had if you put

`DB 0x88, 0xD8`

at the exact same place in your program.

You'll understand that the above is greatly simplified. E.g. a typical ELF binary can easily contain 20 sections. It too is somewhat specific for Intel, but specific is easier to understand than abstract.

Your example is clearly a booting situation. It is not complete because the HelloString is missing. Now if we added it to the end of the program, HelloString is remembered as an address, i.e. a number. While assembling the MOV SI,.. instruction a hole was left to fill that number in. After processing the whole file once, the HelloString address is known and the assembler fills it in.

Groetjes Albert

Comment: Technically, I just wanted to know how this would work from a bare machine (i.e. after boot, instructions executed from a single file; no operating system, memory management, kernel, etc.). Just for simplicity, but thanks anyways.

Comment: Be aware that files only exist in an operating system. I've edited my answer to be more specific to your example.